# SQL - unflatten the records

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have such records in my database:

```
IDV | VALUES
1  | VAL1,VAL2
```

Is there a way to unflatten them using the SQL into:

```
   IDV | VALUES
   1   | VAL1
   1   | VAL2
```

?

Thank you

Comment: This is what we call a **broken** schema design. That should have been stored in separate rows in the first place. Hopefully, the purpose here it to fix that.

Comment: Basically the answer is "yes". Exactly how depends on your specific platform.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes I know that this is a broken design but this is a  historical system that we are trying to migrate.

Comment: @Stu we are using the snowflake. Ideally I want to make it using the view on the table with broken records

Comment: A quick Google reveals [this might be what you need](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table), did you find this in your research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in this way:

```
create or replace table s1(id int, v string);
insert into s1 values(1, 'val1,val2');
select * from s1;
```

gives me back:

[image]

then for the split part:

```
select id, value from s1, lateral split_to_table(v, ',');
```

gives me back:

[image]